# How to iterate through a file and append data?

Tags: unix, awk

In my awk code, I am stuck trying to find a way to iterate through file (data1.txt) and and append line of file 
and count line of file if the 
substr($0,29,2)of the line of file == "04"

data1.txt

6597243042          20160305001100003140152852153019000127000200
6597243042          20160305001100003140170306190306020000000200
6597243042          20160305001100003140170552190552020000000200
6597243042          20160305001100003140201430201543000113000400
6592311319          20160305041100003460072719072839000120001200
6592311319          20160305041100003460072927072952000025001200

which in this case only 2 lines fulfill the condition (substr($0,29,2)=="04")

```
    Filename="def"
    file="data1.txt"
    #awk '{count1=0}'
    while IFS= read line
    do

       awk '{ if (substr($0,29,2)=="04") {print substr($0,29,4)}}' 

    done <"$file"
```

Comment: You would have better luck and responses on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't understand your text. I would try to edit it to better English, but I simply can't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding about awk - you do not need to write an external or internal loop to iterate through the file, that's what awk DOES. You just need to write the `<condition> { <action> }`  that you want executed on each line. Edit your question to at least provide the expected output given your posted input as right now we cant tell what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

To do what it LOOKS like you're trying to do is just:

```
awk '{print $0, (substr($0,29,2)=="04") ? substr($0,29,4) : "")}' "$file"
```

but your input file doesn't HAVE any cases where the 29/30th chars are 04 so idk...

Comment: I think you are on the right track, though I suspect OP wants to count the matching lines too.